# Averaging a column in php array

Tags: php, arrays, average

I have a tab-delimited text file that looks like this:  http://realmonitor.com/nick-stuff/210320.AVG.txt

I can get it into an array OK:  http://realmonitor.com/nick-stuff/avg.php

but can't figure out how to average on columns.

Trying to get the average for the values that appear below each of the headers - 593, 594, 595, etc.

Any help would be much appreciated!

My code to get the file into the array:

```
    <?php

    $file = "210320.AVG.txt";// Your Temp Uploaded file
    $nowavg = array();
    $cols2 = array();
    ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', true);

    $fh = fopen($file, 'r');
    $i = 0;

    while (($line = fgetcsv($fh, 1000, "\t")) !== false) {
      $nowavg[] = $line;

       }

    $j = 1;

    for ($j = 8; $j != 23; $j++)   {

    $cols2[$j][0] = $nowavg[$j][0];

    // $j++;

       }

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($nowavg); 
    echo "</pre>";

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($cols2); 
    echo "</pre>";

    ?>
```

Added for clarity after comments:

Right.  I guess I wouldn't be keen on clicking on links either.

Here's what the AVG file looks like:

```
593 594 595 611 612 613 1214    1215    1216    1547    1548    1549    1565    1566    1567
```

03:59:49    1827    1796    1784    1992    1922    1939    1968    1925    1910    2248    2231    2254    1751    1755    1751
04:59:47    1893    1863    1835    2048    2000    2030    1955    1908    1901    2254    2222    2237    1801    1791    1792
05:59:39    2021    1990    1981    2060    2022    2038    2032    1986    1967    2252    2233    2248    1777    1790    1794
06:59:45    2042    1979    1957    2116    2077    2084    2050    1988    1979    2256    2232    2241    1848    1852    1856
07:59:44    2047    2000    1995    2124    2105    2112    2068    2021    2004    2217    2158    2145    1871    1896    1891
08:59:46    2081    2048    2023    2123    2127    2107    2019    1972    1966    2204    2176    2202    1827    1841    1851
09:59:43    2080    2045    2019    2135    2130    2132    2044    2001    1990    2232    2192    2220    1783    1842    1796
10:59:47    2101    2070    2011    2144    2156    2143    1995    1957    1941    2237    2203    2225    1798    1883    1820
11:59:48    2108    2139    2055    2141    2171    2137    2049    2002    1975    2160    2134    2200    1780    1864    1796
12:59:48    2084    2165    2030    2101    2152    2082    2096    2057    2044    2167    2139    2200    1756    1902    1754
13:59:56    1878    2130    1804    2056    2067    2011    1878    1874    1845    2165    2148    2160    1732    1950    1714
14:59:52    1784    1868    1784    1812    1821    1799    1963    1932    1893    2021    1978    2023    1580    1728    1560
15:59:51    1732    1746    1755    1807    1814    1819    1953    1902    1864    1846    1808    1814    1551    1559    1539
16:59:53    1609    1615    1620    1617    1623    1620    1877    1824    1803    1802    1746    1766    1542    1546    1524
17:59:13    1588    1594    1594    1609    1611    1609    1753    1730    1691    1778    1749    1731    1523    1543    1511

And here's what I'd like to see:

593 594 595 ...
2000    2134    1985

Where the first row of the desired result is the header row of the AVG file and the row below is an average of each column of numbers in the AVG file.

Comment: I'm sure a lot of people hesitate to click on links. It's far better, an actually a SO requirement, to post all necessary components in the actual question.

Answer (score 0):

This code tries to reduce the processing and intermediate storing of values.  It reads the file in and maintains a running total for each column as well as a count of the rows.

It first extracts the header row with the 593 etc.  (removes the blank field off the front), then reads each row.  Each value is then totalled up and after the loop it outputs the heading with the total divided by the row count...

```
$fh = fopen($file, 'r');

$headings = fgetcsv($fh, null, "\t");
array_shift($headings);
$totals = array_fill(0, count($headings), 0);
$rows = 0;
while (($line = fgetcsv($fh, null, "\t")) !== false) {
    array_shift($line);
    foreach ( $line as $position => $value )    {
        $totals[$position] += $value;
    }
    $rows ++;
}

foreach ( $headings as $position => $name ) {
    echo $name. "=" . ( $totals[$position] / $rows ).PHP_EOL;
}
```

which gives...

```
593=1925
594=1936.5333333333
595=1883.1333333333
611=1992.3333333333
612=1986.5333333333
613=1977.4666666667
1214=1980
1215=1938.6
1216=1918.2
1547=2122.6
1548=2089.9333333333
1549=2111.0666666667
1565=1728
1566=1782.8
1567=1729.9333333333
=0
```

Comment: Thanks VERY much!  This is what I'm looking for.  A most excellent resource!

Comment: Turns out I was supposed to be doing this for only the three lines that start with 03:59, 04:59 and 05:59.  Any hint on how to limit the calculation to those lines?

Comment: You can add a check at the end of the loop for the number of rows processed - `    if ( $rows > 2 )    {        break;    }`